# Efficient clustering algorithm for nearly uniformly distributed data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis

I'm playing around with natural language processing and I'm trying to cluster news article titles. I turned the titles into vectors, but they are nearly uniformly distributed. There are small clusters of 2-3 news articles, but most news articles should be in their own clusters.

I tried using k-means, but articles rarely change clusters because the data is fairly uniform. The initial random clusters end up being the final clusters.

I tried agglomerative clustering and it works great for a small data set (a few hundred articles). However, it takes a long time because it's at least O(n^2).

Is there any efficient algorithm to cluster nearly uniformly distributed data?

For example, if my data is a set of real numbers, it could look like this:

1 2 3 4 4.1 5 6

In this case, the clusters should be: (1), (2), (3), (4, 4.1), (5), (6).
Is there a better way to do this than agglomerative clustering?

Comment: Isn't it contradictory to cluster uniform data ?

Comment: If your data is "nearly uniform" then i) there are no clusters, and ii) you did something wrong in preprocessing. Text is  ot *supposed* to be uniform, but Zipf distributed. k-means is also a very bad choice for such data - it does not allow noise (articles in no cluster).

Comment: What I mean by nearly uniform is that there aren't obvious partitions that can split all of the data. Since k-means is used to partition data, it doesn't work well on my data. There are obvious small clusters of <5 nodes, but there should be anything better than O(n^2) to find these clusters.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort your data.
2. Choose a threshold value (see step 4)
3. Iterate through your data
4. If the difference between the current value and the 1st value of the current cluster is less than the threshold, put them into the same cluster, otherwise start a new cluster.

This should be O(n log n) due to the sorting.

Comment: O(n log n) with *extremely* low constant factors, because sorting is so well optimized. So effectively, it's as good as other linear procedures.

Comment: I'm representing my articles as n-dimensional unit vectors, where n is usually a few thousand. Would sorting this help? I'm guessing I should sort on the first dimension, then second, and so on.

Comment: If you have many dimensions, sorting won't help. Your example made me think you could reduce the problem to one dimension.

Comment: @Linksku: "sort on the first dimension, then second, and so on": you can't do that.